# Referrall clicks from my site not showing up on clients reports

Tags: google-analytics

Hi I have a web site that has a number of clients on it I track every time some one click on the link on their page on my site that takes them to the clients own web site I track via my CMS program Once they click on the link it records as a click thur which goes in to a report.

It will only record 1 click a day from the same IP in my system. I can sent my client a report  to show them people are finding their site via our web site but it seems that Google is not picking all or in some cases none of  them up and  one client said they had no visit at all my our site last month. But my CMS records 20 people clicking on the link that takes them to their own site from their page on my site.

Is this common? And what should I do to fix it or advice my clients ?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics is not always 100% accurate and sadly some slip though the net, but its close enough, I assume we are talking low amount of clicks and this is most likely the problem.

The problem here is that your using a CMS to record clicks and he/she is using Google Analytic to monitor low volume of clicks - They could have JavaScript disabled or Cookies which would cause a imbalance of the data, also Google works of unique visitors monthly unless reviewing singular days, your monthly report will look different to there's.

There's a better way of doing this, setup a landing page on the clients website that then redirects to the correct page, that way they can clearly see people being redirected in access.log and Analytics . Also you should assume some are bots are following it.